# How can i automatically generate colModel in jqgrid based on json datas?

Tags: javascript, json, jqgrid

I've got a simply jqgrid and i want to generate columns based on variable datas.
There is a way to do this?

Comment: So based on JSON data, you want to dynamically build a jqGrid colModel? I'm sure this is possible, but not without a lot of work and thought. If you can post your attempts, maybe we (the SO community) can help you a little better. We're not here to write your code, just help with questions you may have :-)

Comment: Of course, i just wanna know if there is a method or property to automatically this. If not, i'll write the code by my self, of course ;)

Comment: There is no built-in jQGrid method to accomplish this. You'll have to write up the solution yourself.